# Header background not loading

Tags: html, css

my background is not loading. It is embedded in the header tag loading through the style sheet. See css below:

```
header{
margin: 0;
background-image: url(/images/sagage_header900.png) no-repeat ;
display: block;    
}
```

Thanx in advance!

Comment: Is the url path correct? Did you check that?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `no-repeat` in `background-image` property.

Try this :

```
background: url(/images/sagage_header900.png) no-repeat;
```

OR

```
background-image: url(/images/sagage_header900.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing no-repeat

```
background-image: url(/images/sagage_header900.png);
```

if you want to add background-repeat:

```
background-repeat: no-repeat
```

If still doesn't work, try adding `!important` to background-image as follow:

```
background-image: url(/images/sagage_header900.png)!important;
```

Comment: Don't use important... If he want to overwrite an existing rule, just define more your selector

Comment: @CyrilBeeckman I agree with you. Adding more selector is a good idea instead of adding !important.